# Java - Static Generic Type using Comparable

Tags: java, generics, types, static, comparable

Alright, so I've been trying to implement a simple binary search tree that uses a comparable data type by default.

Ignoring all my other methods in the class, this is the general setup I have which I think is pretty standard:

```
public class BSTNode<E extends Comparable<? super E>>{
     E data;
     BSTNode<E> left;
     BSTNode<E> right;
     //and I'm trying to define a static method(inside of the class) like this:
     public static <E> String displayAscending(BSTNode<E> node){} 
}
```

But the compiler isn't liking it. Now, I'm kind of new to generic types so I'll explain my understanding of what this does and that might help you in figuring out what's wrong with my thinking.

E extends Comparable
So basically an object E that is an extension of Comparable. Comparable having an element that is an ancestor of E, which essentially is an abstract way of saying E can be compared with its other elements using the Comparable interface.

Then in my static method I'm trying to pass the BSTNode recursively. I can't seem to wrap my head around why it's not working. I know If I pass `BSTNode<?>` it works fine, but that seems dangerous. If someone could explain to me WHY this isn't working I could try and find another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
public static <E extends Comparable<? super E>> String displayAscending(BSTNode<E> node)
```

Comment: It works if you do that. Same with BSTNode<?>, but I'm wondering why referencing E the way I am gives me problems. I'd like to ensure that the object being passed is a comparable one.

Comment: Also, I got this to work: `public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> String displayAscending(BSTNode<T> node)`

I would still like to know why my above code is giving me problems.

Comment: It's giving problems because the `E` isn't given any type bounds in `displayAscending`, but it needs to satisfy your `E extends Comparable<? super E>` on the class to be used in `BSTNode<E>`. What letter you use (`E`/`T`/whatever) is irrelevant, so it still works when you change to using `T`.

Comment: Oh I could have sworn it gave me an error when I used E, but I just tried it and it's fine. So basically, because it's static I have to ensure that it covers the restrictions of the class. I think I have a better understanding of how static methods work now. Thanks :).